# Is there a way to get the number of threads used inside a Docker container?

Tags: docker

I know I can use `docker container top` to see the running processes of a container, but is there a different command to see the number of threads? Or does `docker container top` already do that?

Comment: If you are interested only in number of running processes check this: https://linuxtweaksforu.wordpress.com/2015/07/07/command-to-count-the-number-of-processes-running-in-linux/ 
(don't forget that by running this command you will also create additional threads which you should subtract from result)

Answer (score 1):

the correct (approximate) command is 'docker stats' or 'docker container stats' specifically the PID column; it includes all processes and threads.

Comment: OneLiner:  `docker stats  --no-stream --format '{{.PIDs}}\t{{.Name}}'  | sort -nr`